# Writing inteceptor to prevent request to route to controller on specific condition

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am using interceptor to get the status of mongodb connectivity using flag variable. MongoDB is trying to connect at application startup and I am setting a boolean flag. This flag value is already I am setting in session scope on login. I am using interceptor to get the flag value from session and if flag is false then dont want to route the request to controller. Hope I have explained my problem in brief.

Therefore, I've written an interceptor that intercepts only some request mapping URL's based on a flag variable. If flag variable is true then controller method executes and populate model data and if flag is false then requesting URL page should display with some error message to the requesting URL page.

I am facing struggle in case of returning false condition in prehandle() as prehandle method return type is boolean so I can't return a new ModelAndView object from there and if I use response.sendError() then an error page comes on the requesting URL but I want to render my view page on requesting URL but also make sure that controller method should not be throw.

Is it possible to write an interceptor that render requesting URL page by adding a custom object but not passes to the controller for the same URL mapping.

I also tried response.sendRedirect but it results an infinite loop to interceptor method entry method because same interceptor invoked for URL.

One workaround for me is to add seperate URL mapping such as //errorMessage mapping in each controller class whichever using the interceptor but it defeat the pupose of using the interceptor for the approach.

I am also attaching the code for the reference.

```
package com.renovite.ripps.ap.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import com.renovite.ripps.ap.common.AdminPortalMsgsPropFileReader;
import com.renovite.ripps.ap.common.Constants;
import com.renovite.ripps.ap.common.ErrorCodes;
import com.renovite.ripps.ap.ui.controller.AdminController;

/**
 * The Class MongoDBConnectionInterceptor.
 */


/**
 * @author Satyam Kaushik
 *
 * 
 */
public class MongoDBConnectionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter#preHandle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.lang.Object)
     */

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDBConnectionInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler ) throws Exception {

       Boolean isMongoDBConnected =  (Boolean)request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.IS_MONGODB_CONNECTED_SESSION);
       if(!isMongoDBConnected){
           logger.error(Constants.IS_MONGODB_CONNECTED_SESSION);


        String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI().toString();
        String targetMappingURL = url.split("/")[2];   //



response.sendRedirect(targetMappingURL );  //it results an infinite loop
    //response.sendError("Connection failed to MongoDB");    // Error page on the requesting URL.
       }return isMongoDBConnected;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interceptor may not be the wisest choice here, as it is too far outside the annotated controller mechanism. Instead, I'd suggest using a `@ControllerAdvice`, something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages="com.yourcompany")
public class MyAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    // add params as needed, but return type must be void
    public void dispatch(){
       if(somethingIsBad()) throw new SomethingIsBadException();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SomethingIsBadException.class)
    // this method can have any parameter or return type that
    // a @RequestMapping method can.
    public SomeBusinessObject recover(){
        return new SomeBusinessObject();
    }

}
```

This way, you can use all annotations and return types supported by `@RequestMapping` in your exception handler.

**Reference:**
`@ControllerAdvice` [**Docs**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller-advice), [**JavaDocs**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

Comment: it is too far outside the annotated controller mechanism means ??

Comment: No of course not. You are the one who talked about interceptors, and those are even further away from annotated controllers, but sure, you can do all of this in a controller class as well

Comment: I dont want to route the request to  some Controllers (which requires MongoDB connectivity) in case if application is not connected to MongoDB.This is not a solution for my case.

Comment: .I am using interceptor to get the status of mongodb connectivity using flag variable. MongoDB is trying to connect at application startup and I am setting a boolean flag. This flag value is already I am setting in session scope on login.  I am using interceptor to get the flag value from session and if flag is false then dont want to route the request to controller. Hope I have explained my problem in brief.

Comment: @Satyam you should add that to your question, not a comment to an answer

Comment: @Floyd : I've edited the subject line and initial statement.Thanks !

Comment: "An interceptor may not be the wisest choice here, as it is too far outside the annotated controller mechanism."???

The handlerIntrerceptor takes into consideration forwards so as to catch a call to the same API as well as to other internal APIs using the same request/token so this is exactly what you want to use. **This is what the handler interceptor is for**.